# get facebook video link via video id

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to `fetch Facebook video` link **(https://www.facebook.com/messagetv/videos/2453520221381276/)** using `video Id` in swift to get `watch link or download link`

(https://video.fymy11.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.241302/74282426_142122027138891_3868680309353445136_n.mp4?blabla).

I've tried different ways like graph api but no success. In graph api when i'm trying to access but this occurs [image: this error]

Is there someone who can guide me that is that possible to fetch `download link` from `facebook url`?
Thanks in advance

Comment: what is unclear about the error message from the graph api? also, scraping is not allowed, you MUST use the api.

Comment: how can i give public content access because while giving permissions i am unable to fine manage pages here permissions: [.publicProfile])

Comment: you have to apply for it

Comment: is it possible that i can get test data before applying for review

Comment: you can use a page token of a page you own, for example

Comment: Thank you i obtained the page token of my own page and its working perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Test this with a Page Token of a Page you own.
- If you want to get video links of Pages you do not own, apply for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS).